# Spring Boot is not initializing data on startup with Spring JDBC getting errors on writing queries in a data.sql file

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, h2-console

I am learning Spring Framework from online tutorials. In the tutorial, the instructor is using Spring JDBC and the [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_%28DBMS%29) database and a *data.sql* file to populate tables. He also changed the dialect from "General SQL" to "MySQL" dialect as we are going to use MySQL in future videos, so I am just following the tutorial.

All just went well, but when I created data.sql and changed the dialect in my classpath, I was getting errors on a table name like this:

> Unable to resolve <table> and table names and columns are showing in red color as errors.

I don't know what's happening, and I have tried every solution on the Internet. I am attaching my source code and data.SQL screenshot.

- [data.sql file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQWNB.png)
- [Entity file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI0eA.png)

Comment: This is an **IntelliJ** question. It is not actually about Spring JDBC, Spring Boot, or H2. Also note these are not errors, they are just info that you haven't wired up IntelliJ to inspect your local database. Doing that enables nice features but is totally optional. Aside: your only errors in the .java file are because you misspelled "_description_".

Comment: The title of this question says "Spring Boot is not initialize Data on Startup" — if you have saving some sort of issue with Spring Boot and startup, that is not described here, and that probably should go into a new question. Please clean up the title & tags of this question to reflect the problem described & answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually seeing errors, that is, IntelliJ doesn't know enough about your database to know whether you have any problem that should generate an error.

- You need to have a database.
- Your first screenshot has a link that says "Configure data source". Click that link, and [go through the process to set up IntelliJ to work with your database](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/relational-databases.html#first-steps-with-goland).

Then you will be able to use IntelliJ's DB features, if you want to (or if your course requires you to use those features).

In this case, you will probably need to already have a table called `category` in that database with the right layout, or you *will* start seeing errors.